# Receive data from a servlet without submitting

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am currently working on a online store where the store page is a jsp file. Then the information is forwarded to a servlet and it is displayed on another jsp file. I have how many items are left stored on the servlet.

How can I make it so when I load the page, the first jsp file has amount of items left?

This is my first jsp file:

```
<html>
   <form action="ProcessInfo" method="post"> 
      <label>First Name : </label>
      <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
      <label>Last Name : </label>
      <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
      <label>Contact Info : </label>
      <input type="text" name="Contact_Info" value="IG,SC,etc"><br><br>
      <label>M&M $1 per </label>
      <input type="text" id ="MM" name="MM" value="0" ><br><br>
      <label>Skittles $1 per </label>
      <input type="text" id="Skittles" name="Skittles" value="0" ><br><br>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Send"> 
   </form>
```

This is my servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String url ="/DisplayInfo.jsp";
    String MM = request.getParameter("MM");
    String Skittles = request.getParameter("Skittles");
    String Contact_Info = request.getParameter("Contact_Info");
    //I create a customer object here called customer
    request.setAttribute("customer", customer);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    }
```

This is my jsp that displays the info

```
<html>
    <label>Name:</label>
    ${cust.getfName()}<br>
    <label>Meeting Location:</label>
    ${cust.getMeeting_Location()}<br>
    <label>Contact Information:</label>
    ${cust.getContact_Info()}<br>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to fetch data from servlet without submiting a form you can do ajax call !!

Comment: You can store your item left  in `HttpSession` .